# Reduce the query response time, need to optimise the query

Tags: sql, oracle, query-performance

I wrote a query which fetches the record of NULL DAYS (Occasion,weekoff,emergency holiday), later I implemented the same in GUI, so my admin can able to see the list, it will take minutes to load the data, even in my SQL developer.

How to reduce the execution time?

Here is the query

```
SELECT *
FROM
  (SELECT s.null_id ,
    STRING_AGG(DISTINCT s.city) city_id ,
    STRING_AGG(DISTINCT c.name) cityName ,
    STRING_AGG(DISTINCT s.location) location_id ,
    STRING_AGG(DISTINCT l.name) locationName ,
    STRING_AGG(DISTINCT s.sublocation) sublocation_id ,
    STRING_AGG(DISTINCT sl.name) sublocationName ,
    s.department ,
    s.fromtodate ,
    s.todate ,
    s.remark ,
    s.status ,
    s.update_date ,
    s.update_by ,
    s.delete_status ,
    s.update_by_name ,
    uu.name updatedBy ,
    row_number() OVER(ORDER BY s.null_id) rnum
  FROM nullday s
  LEFT OUTER JOIN userdetail uu
  ON s.update_by = uu.user_id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN city c
  ON ','
    || s.city
    || ',' LIKE '%,'
    ||c.CITY_ID
    ||',%'
  LEFT OUTER JOIN location l
  ON ','
    || s.location
    || ',' LIKE '%,'
    ||l.LOCATION_ID
    ||',%'
  LEFT OUTER JOIN sublocation sl
  ON ','
    || s.sublocation
    || ',' LIKE '%,'
    ||sl.SUBLOCATION_ID
    ||',%'
  WHERE s.null_id = s.null_id
  GROUP BY s.null_id,
    s.location,
    s.sublocation,
    s.department,
    s.fromtodate,
    s.todate,
    s.remark ,
    s.status,
    s.update_date,
    s.update_by,
    s.delete_status,
    s.update_by_name,
    uu.name
  ORDER BY s.fromtodate ASC
  ) mytbl
WHERE rnum < :max_val
AND rnum   > :min_val
```

I am not able to figure it out, whether the `joins` or `LISTAGG` takes the time to load the query.

NULLDAY  Table data format

[image]

Comment: The first problem is that your data is stuffed full of CSV lists that you're then using to join to other tables based on whether a value is/not present in the CSV list. Normalise your database properly..

Comment: Any other suggestion related to the current query, because our database is very huge, we are not in position to normalise it will badly impact on our project

Comment: Show some data, but all in I'm going with "no; it was a terrible design decision to allow nulldays to have multiple cities associated with them by putting a comma separated list of city IDs in the nullday record. If the relationship between nullday and city is many:many, then there should have been a middleman table, nullday_city to break the relationship into two many:one relationships". Sort your data out, or it will come back to bite you again, and again. You can do this additively (make the middleman table, populate it from the CSV column, maintain both, phase out the CSV)

Comment: ps; the "it was a terrible design decision" critique doesn't stop at nullday:city - looks like you've done it everywhere. Horrific :o If you're determined to persist with it, do your database a favour and have the front end unpack that data; don't get the database to do it

Comment: attached a png file in which I capture the NULLDAY table data

Comment: Why are you not able to fix the actual problem you have? It seems it has already badly impacted your project because you're here and you have a problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the significant issues here that you join tables on expressions, not on actual columns. This rules out the usage of an index that could potentially speed up the process.

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN city c
  ON ','
    || s.city
    || ',' LIKE '%,'
    ||c.CITY_ID
    ||',%'
```

A possible solution could be to create a temporary (or helper) table where you create separate rows using the comma-separated list and the original primary key. You can use that to retrieve the primary key faster.

A generic approach could be the following:

- Can we break down long queries into smaller chunks?
- Can we use temporary tables instead of the join expressions?
- Can we design the temporary tables to replace LEFT JOINs with INNER JOINs?
- Can we reduce the number of DISTINCTs?
- Can we remove the ORDER BY?
- Can we remove (or rework by using temporary tables) the *row_number() OVER(ORDER BY s.null_id)*?
- Can we redesign the database to save data as it should be in a relational database? (Proper columns and records can be used in an index, comma-separated strings not.)

There's not much more I could suggest without knowing more details. I hope it helps.

**Edit based on the data uploaded**

You should extract the comma-separated lists and create proper one-to-many relationships. Use permanent tables if you are allowed to change the database structure, otherwise use temp tables when you rework your query.

Comment: okkk agreed, can you implement the aforesaid mentioned point in the same query

Comment: Start with creating  **location** and **sublocation** tables by breaking down the comma-separated lists. This would dramatically reduce the query time.

Comment: What I mean is to create **nullday_city**, **nullday_location** and **nullday_sublocation**, where each record has the primary key(s) of **nullday** table, and a single _city_, _location_ and _sublocation_ number, respectively.

In your query you can join this tables to **nullday** and also to the **city**, **location** and **sublocation** tables. For example the **nullday_city** will be placed "between" **nullday** and **city**.

Comment: In the current query, the system has to do the concatenation for every record in the **nullday** table. By using the new tables, you can create joins on native columns, instead of expressions. These columns can be indexed, which improves the speed even more.

Comment: Ok Miklos thank you so much, I thin the repetitive concatenation lead to low performance issue. One last request, can you demonstrate with some example, so I will discuss the same with my technical director, so our DB developer will able to implement the same

Comment: Without creating a case study on this, you can prove your point using the point below:

1.  Creating the new tables is one-time activity, running the query and calculating the expressions is a regular process;

2. By storing comma-separated values in a relational database, you prevent the database engine to use any indexes that would normally speed up the query.